# lotus notes signature error, "must chose filename"

Tags: lotus-notes, signature

who in the pass tried to add an image to her signature, not too sure how she's done it but now she cant change her signature.

I used to be able to force it using the webmail signature function but thats not working anymore and anyway im way over due to fix this problem.

everytime she opens her preferences and when we want to modify her signature i have a popup windows that tells me :

field contains incorect value
“since you have chosen to append and HTML or image as a signature, you must include the filename that you wish to use.”

if i uncheck the "automaticaly add signature" option i dont get this error but as soon i re check it i get the window, even if theres nothing in the signature window, i've deleted everything in the text box same problem.

I reinstalled windows on another computer with our Ghost image, and on this clean install she has the same error so i guess its saved somewhere on my domino server

thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably an error in her calendar profile. Use some tool to edit her calendar profile directly or just delete it.

Comment: You have no clue how much time i spend on this problem...

heres the youtube video i followed to redo the callender profile for futur reference 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2LaXYCtDZc#t=82